# Date mismatch in excel report from sql database

Tags: sql-server, excel, date

I am extracting excel report from a SQL Server database (SQL Express 2008 R2) which contains date field. when date is greater than 12 everything is perfect but when date is smaller than 13 then date and month replace position.

[image]

Invalid date rows 2,7,11,13,20.

Comment: SQL Server database?

Comment: Change your query to select a string representation of the date instead of the date itself.

Comment: Excel formula is applied on this column, will it affect  other column results.

Comment: Assuming this is an excel macro, add a function to format the column.